# Отправка через GCM без уведомления в шторке

Tags: android, spring, firebase, google-cloud-messages

Задача следующая.

Пишу служебный список задач под андроид.
Идея сделать список задач для каждого пользователя. Задачи могут уходить и приходить, пользователь может назначить задачу тебе.

Нужно, чтобы backend отправлял задачи android- приложению.
Хотел сделать это через **Google Cloud Messaging**, но я видел примеры только с уведомлениями в шторке.
Но мне не нужны уведомления в шторке. Мне по факту нужно просто отправить информацию с бекенда и обработать её на клиенте в Android.

Возможно ли это? И как это реализовать?
Прошу объяснить или скинуть ссылку на данную информацию.

Прошу **не** дизлайкать мой вопрос ибо ответа на этот вопрос нет в stackoverflow

Android (kotlin)
Backend - Spring (java)

Comment: в шторке у тебя уведомления потому что ты отправляешь Notification, а если ты оправишь те же данные, но внутри Data то никаких нотификаций у тебя в шторке не будет, даже если приложение будет закрыто. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: {
  "message":{
    "token":"....",
    "data":{
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2"
    }
  }
}